# p:inputSwitch doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I added an `<p:inputSwitch>` in my JSF page, but this is not working. 
Get and set method is not called when I change the stat

The JSF page :

```
<p:inputSwitch value="#{SystemController.statSystem}" />
```

The managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SystemController extends AbstractController implements Serializable {
private Boolean statSystem;

public Boolean getStatSystem() {
return statSystem;
}

public void setStatSystem(Boolean statSystem) {
this.statSystem=statSystem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @BalusC, Yes the `<p:inputSwitch>` is inside a `<h:form>` exactly as shown in PrimeFaces

Answer (score 2):

I added an ajax tag and it works ! Get and Set methods are working now.

```
<p:inputSwitch value="#{SystemController.statSystem}" >
<p:ajax  />
</p:inputSwitch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statSystem variable is not initialized.
Init like:

```
private Boolean statSystem = false;
```

or instead change data type to primitive:

```
private boolean statSystem;
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but it doesn't work. thank you. i will try to use an `<p:ajax />` tag